# ggplot plot boxplot by label per column?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame:

```
x1 x2  x3    y1 y2  y3 z1 z2   z3    label
1  54  -9    45 323 1  9  12  -0.1   1
5  21  -33.3 54 0.9 98 12 -87  5     2
12 1.3  0    23  12 65  7 -8   15    1
```

I want to plot a faceted plot that will compare each column by label.

For example x1 values: 2 boxplots one for label == 1, and label == 2.
9 facets, each own 2 box plots for each label.

I am trying to do this like this:

```
test <- gather(df, key, value, -label)

ggplot(test, aes(x = factor(label), y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap(~ key)
```

Please advise how to this right?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, IMO your code (since edit) produces exactly the output you describe.

Comment: @jaySf I just thought I am missing something, maybe there is command for such tasks. Everyday learning something new from the experts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have the data frame in the long format. With package `reshape2` you can do it like this.

```
m <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "label")

ggplot(m, aes(x = label, y = variable)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap( ~ variable)
```

Like the OP said in a comment, with package `tidyr` this would be done as follows.

```
test <- tidyr::gather(df, key, value, -label)

ggplot(test, aes(x = label, y = key)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_wrap( ~ key)
```

**Data.**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
x1 x2  x3    y1 y2  y3 z1 z2   z3    label
1  54  -9    45 323 1  9  12  -0.1   1
5  21  -33.3 54 0.9 98 12 -87  5     2
12 1.3  0    23  12 65  7 -8   15    1  
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Same with tidyr::gather?

Comment: "Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : names do not match previous names"

Comment: @steves With the data you have posted, I am not getting errors, everything works as expected.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Your code does not produce OP's expected output, there's only one boxplot for each label.

Comment: @jaySf Apparently it does, the OP has accepted the answer... And I really don't know whether there is just one boxplot or two touching each other. I would be able to see only with more data.